# Private npm for clients

Tags: npm, npmjs

I'm working in a library of components which I would like to deploy to npm.
Everything is working great, however, I want my packages to be visible only for my customer, and not to everybody.

I was reading that I can create a private npm, but in that case, only the collaborators have access to it.

I dont want my customers to be my collaborators, I want they to have access, but not be able to edit it.

Is there a way to do this? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products like Artifactory provide the ability to publish your npm modules and decide who gets access and with what kind of permissions.